# How to check the maximum number of std::placeholders?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, standards, language-implementation

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders):

> The `std::placeholders` namespace contains the placeholder objects `[_1, . . ., _N]` where `N` is an implementation defined maximum number.

I checked *libstdc++*'s header file `functional` and found the `N` is `29`.

**Is there a standard way to check that? Say, a feature test macro?**

Comment: Why do you even need this? trying to use one above the limit would anyway not build. Also, this is kind of deprecated with lambdas.

Comment: Interestingly experimenting with Wandbox and Godbolt it seems there can be quite a difference: I get 29 for GCC on Wandbox and Godbolt, 10 for Clang on Wandbox and 29 for Clang on Godbolt and 20 for MSVC in Godbolt.

Comment: Also, you can [define](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/is_placeholder#Example) your own placeholders and used them if you really need a lot and don't want to be restricted by the standard library implementation